# why im getting this err.anyone can tel em a code for spyder that can be used to convert word2vector

Tags: python, spyder

i am getting this err msg:

> File "", line 1, in 
>   model=gensim.models.word2vec(tok_corpus,min_count=2,size =32)
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import gensim
#import corpora, models,similarities
os.chdir("D:\Mphil");
df=pd.read_csv('wn-data-eng.tab');
corpus=df.values.tolist()
#y=df['lemma'].valuestolist()
#corpus=x*y
tok_corpus=[nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in corpus]
model=gensim.models.word2vec(tok_corpus,min_count=2,size =32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that `word2vec` is a module. You want to call `Word2Vec`. Internally, the `gensim.model` module does `from .word2vec import Word2Vec` - and you end up with both the module and its contained function in the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

just use `Word2Vec` instead of `word2vec`:

```
Word2Vec(tok_corpus,min_count=2,size =32)
```